# TypeScript Model

Tags: typescript, model

```
{
    "title": {
        "de-DE": "German",
        "fr-FR": "French",
        "en-CA": "English"
    },
    "image": "/tile.jpg",
    "url": "/url/to/version"
}
```

I have this JSON that i request and my model looks like this:

```
export class ThisIsMyModel {
    title: string;
    image: string;
    url: string;
}
```

How is the correct way, to have a sub field for the locales, something like this:

```
export class ThisIsMyModel {
    title: string
    [
       de-DE: string;
       fr-FR: string;
       en-CA: string;
    ];
    image: string;
    url: string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the set of languages is limited to those you listed, you can use this definition. Also if you are just going to cast the object JSON to the model type, you should use an interface not a class:

```
export interface ThisIsMyModel {
    title: {
       'de-DE': string;
       'fr-FR': string;
       'en-CA': string;
    };
    image: string;
    url: string;
}
```

If the languages are not known you can define an object with a string indexer:

```
export interface ThisIsMyModel {
    title: {
        [name: string]: string
    };
    image: string;
    url: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The TS definition you've provided isn't going to work for the data you have. `title` could have type `{ [key: string]: string }` if you want. If it *could* could also be a simple string, you could try `{ [key: string]: string} | string` and deal with one or the other case at runtime.

Comment: `{ [key: "de-DE"|"fr-FR"|"en-CA"]: string}` will not work, the index parameter MUST be `string` or `number`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks. I've updated the answer.